# give a font to gridview that doesn't exist in all systems

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I give a font to `gridview` that doesn't exist in all systems.If is there a way that i put the font in project folder that all users can see it without having that?

Comment: I think this is more of a CSS question than C# and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `@font-face` CSS attribute to specify a custom font face:

http://return-true.com/2010/05/css-3-custom-fonts-using-font-face/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myCustomFont;
    src: url(path/to/my/font);
}


.gridViewClass
{
   font-family: myCustomFont;
}
```

Comment: if it decrease speed of loading site?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I would expect so as the browser would have to download the font into temporary files, rather than read the font from its own machine (like with standard fonts).